# Set Hadoop output folder replication in Java code before execution

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a Hadoop job and I want to set the replication number of output folder to 1 and I want to do this inside the Java code. The default value on our server is 3. An other import aspect is to set the replication number before the output is written. Meaning that I do not want to write the whole output with 3 replicas and only then decrease it to 1. I want that before it begins to write to output folder it is set so, that there will be only one replication. The reason for this is that the output can be quite large and I want to spare some space.

```
@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    /** Get configuration */
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    conf.setStrings("args", args);

    /** Job configuration */
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "HadoopSearch");
    job.setJarByClass(Search.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

    /** Set Mapper and Reducer, use identity reducer*/
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class); // identity

    /** Set input and output formats */
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    /** Set input and output path */
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("IN PATH"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("OUT PATH"));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that I can set this using `FileSystem.setReplication(Path p, short s)` but this only works per file and I want it set for the whole folder. I could loop through files inside folder but more importantly, this seems to work only after the job is finished and the files already exsists. As I assume then the processes for replication would already be running and I could hit the problems with disk space which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mapreduce you can set dfs.replication property using set job configuration so that the files created within that job will have the specified replication factor. Hope this will help.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("dfs.replication", "1");
    Job job = new Job(conf);
```